# How to perform Rename and Move operation on Xml elements using xslt Requirement

Tags: xml, xslt

I Have one xml say **INPUT.xml**

```
<paran>
some more attributes
    </paran>
    <child1>
some more attributes
    </child1>
    <child2>
some more attributes
    </child2>
```

I want to perform xslt on it in such a way that it will produce

```
<Parent>
some more attributes
<child>
    some more attributes
 </child>
 <child>
    some more attributes
 </child>
</Parent>
```

As you can see I want to rename the elements as well as move it. How can I Write a xsl for it

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="child1">
  <Child>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </Child>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="child2">
  <Child>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </Child>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="paran">
  <Parents>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </Parents>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Parents">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't see any splitting in your output - and I did not understand this part: "*copy all the elements up to the first file and after the last file and then add the individual file content for each output file*". There is no `file` in your input, so that's entirely cryptic. -- In general, splitting the input into multiple output documents requires an XSLT 2.0 processor, or an XSLT 1.0 processor that supports it as an extension.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Apologise for confusion, I have large contents in the XML like `<AddedParts>` there could be many more I want to slice it down as i describe above as a expected output.

Comment: I am afraid it still makes no sense to me. If you want multiple outputs, then edit your question and show each output separately. -- Also indicate if you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs Do you still think so?

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh That's quite a change in requirement. Now, where exactly are you stuck with this?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I am able to put `<ABC><EFG><PQR>` inside `<BOMComponent>` but the previous one was not deleted. I want to move inside '<BOMComponents>' but it is copying

Comment: Mine requirement is some what bigger so i am asking it step by step

Comment: Please post your existing XSLT so that we can fix it, instead of writing everything from scratch.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I hope now you understand what i am trying to do. i really apologise for creating the ambiguity I am new to java as well as on stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have abstracted the example a little too much. If I take your previous example:

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLECTION>
   <Release NAME="Release" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
      <Transaction>
         <TransactionNumber>17</TransactionNumber>
         <ReleaseNumber>17</ReleaseNumber>
      </Transaction>
   </Release>
   <BOMHeader>
      <ObjectID>OR:wt.part.WTPart:401060081:104375456-1153348282062-33238777-27-83-253-132@icenterv01.ptc.com</ObjectID>
   </BOMHeader>
   <ABC NAME="DeletedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
      <ObjectID>OR:wt.part.WTPartMaster:401058642:104375456-1153348282062-33238777-27-83-253-132@icenterv01.ptc.com</ObjectID>
   </ABC>
   <EFG NAME="AddedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
      <ObjectID>OR:wt.part.WTPartMaster:401058642:104375456-1153348282062-33238777-27-83-253-132@icenterv01.ptc.com</ObjectID>
   </EFG>
   <PQR NAME="ChangedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
      <ObjectID>OR:wt.part.WTPartMaster:401058642:104375456-1153348282062-33238777-27-83-253-132@icenterv01.ptc.com</ObjectID>
   </PQR>
   <BOMComponent/>
</COLLECTION>
```

and apply the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="BOMComponent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <!-- move nodes to here -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../ABC | ../EFG | ../PQR" mode="move"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove nodes from their original place -->
<xsl:template match="ABC | EFG | PQR" />

<!-- rename moved nodes (3x) -->
<xsl:template match="ABC" mode="move">
    <new-ABC>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </new-ABC>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="EFG" mode="move">
    <new-EFG>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </new-EFG>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PQR" mode="move">
    <new-PQR>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </new-PQR>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLECTION>
   <Release NAME="Release" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
      <Transaction>
         <TransactionNumber>17</TransactionNumber>
         <ReleaseNumber>17</ReleaseNumber>
      </Transaction>
   </Release>
   <BOMHeader>
      <ObjectID>OR:wt.part.WTPart:401060081:104375456-1153348282062-33238777-27-83-253-132@icenterv01.ptc.com</ObjectID>
   </BOMHeader>
   <BOMComponent>
      <new-ABC NAME="DeletedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
         <ObjectID>OR:wt.part.WTPartMaster:401058642:104375456-1153348282062-33238777-27-83-253-132@icenterv01.ptc.com</ObjectID>
      </new-ABC>
      <new-EFG NAME="AddedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
         <ObjectID>OR:wt.part.WTPartMaster:401058642:104375456-1153348282062-33238777-27-83-253-132@icenterv01.ptc.com</ObjectID>
      </new-EFG>
      <new-PQR NAME="ChangedBOMComponents" TYPE="Unknown" STATUS="0">
         <ObjectID>OR:wt.part.WTPartMaster:401058642:104375456-1153348282062-33238777-27-83-253-132@icenterv01.ptc.com</ObjectID>
      </new-PQR>
   </BOMComponent>
</COLLECTION>
```

Comment: It almost works only `<BOMComponent>` need to be rename with `<BOMComponents>` can u suggest me with that

Comment: In the template matching `BOMComponent`, use `<BOMComponents>` instead of `<xsl:copy>`.