# How to move Specific XML element using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to move specific element of XML Attribute at specific location using XSL file.

let say I have XML

```
<all>
    <one>Something 1</one>
    <check>
        <present>
            <target> Hello </target>
            <abc> ABC </abc>
        </present>
        <absent> 
            <target> Hi </target>
            <pqr> PQR </pqr>
        </absent>
    </check>
    <action>
        <perform>
            <one>One</one>
            <two>Two</two>
        </perform>
    </action>
</all>
```

I want a output like:

```
<all>
    <one>Something 1</one>
    <check>
        <present>
                     <abc> ABC </abc>
        </present>
        <absent> 
            <target> Hi </target>
            <pqr> PQR </pqr>
        </absent>
    </check>
    <action>
        <perform>
            <one>One</one>
            <two>Two</two>
            <target> Hello </target>
        </perform>
    </action>
</all>
```

For this I write

```
       <xsl:template match= "@*|node()" >
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select= "@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template >
 <xsl:template match= "action" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select= "@*|node()" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select= "../check/present/target" mode= "move" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template >
<xsl:template match="target" mode="move">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

`<target>Hello</target>` is moved under `<action>` but I want it to move inside `<perform>` which is inside `<action>`

Comment: Do you also have a template matching target with mode="move"?

Comment: Well, applying a template that doesn't exist doesn't do anything. See the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650232/how-to-perform-rename-and-move-operation-on-xml-elements-using-xslt-requirement/38659945#38659945 Note that you can use `xsl:copy` if you're not making any changes to the "moved" nodes.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I updated my xsl now I have a template matching target with mode="move"

Comment: Its is done `<xsl:apply-templates select= "../../check/present/target" mode= "move" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put the `target` node under `perform` simply change the template match to match `perform` instead of `action`

```
<xsl:template match="action/perform">
```

Or even this (if `perform` can only ever be under `action`)

```
<xsl:template match="perform">
```

Also, as you are actually not moving a node, but rather adding a new one, and removing an existing one, you would also need a template to ignore the current `target` node

```
<xsl:template match="present/target" />
```

Try this XSLT. Note how I have made the identity template a named template to avoid some code duplication.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select= "@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="present/target" />

    <xsl:template match="action/perform">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select= "@*|node()" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select= "../../check/present/target" mode="move" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template >

    <xsl:template match="target" mode="move">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, if you don't intend to modify the `target` element, you can just use `xsl:copy-of`

Try this too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select= "@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="present/target" />

    <xsl:template match="perform">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select= "@*|node()" />
            <xsl:copy-of select= "../../check/present/target" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```